# Similar gallery to this one for joomla only in HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, joomla

I need similar gallery as this one for joomla - http://www.flashxml.net/list-gallery.html only with CSS and HTML code not flash, since I will need to edit the layout for the gallery. Is there any available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JoomGallery, Phoca Gallery or Simple Image Gallery are the ones I would recommend. You can find lots on the [Joomla Extensions Directory](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/photos-a-images/galleries/photo-gallery)

Answer (score -1):

You should check out Yootheme Widgetkit Gallery